# Perfect Decimal Arithmetic Where Possible

Tags: c#, math

I am using the decimal type in C# to avoid errors introduced by binary floating point arithmetic but still, there will be accuracy errors when dealing with divisions that cause infinite number of digits after the decimal point. Whereas when done manually using fraction format when doing such calculations, it might yield perfect results. Think of the following:

```
decimal a = 32;
decimal b = 65;
decimal c = 130;

decimal d = a / b * c;
```

The calculated result for d is 63.999999999999999999999999999M. But if we did it manually using the fraction format, we could easily find 64.

Is there such a library that organizes this kind of arithmetic into fraction format and carries out a perfect calculation **where possible**.

Calculator on Windows seems to be doing that.

Comment: Curiously enough, if you define the operation as `a * c / b` you will get `64`.

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to achieve?  Integer maths is fast, floating point is slow, decimals are very slow, you are are asking will be extremely slow.  If you are doing monetary calculations, decimal should be fine for most uses, if you are doing interplanetary calculations, integers may be acceptable.

Comment: You could try `BigRational` from BCL: https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/bcl/tree/master/Libraries/BigRational

Comment: @Rotem Well it was just an example for demonstrating the problem. In dynamic calculations, you will not know the numbers you will deal with in advance, hence you will not have the luxury of organizing the formula for a specific case.

Comment: @JohnL. Obviously. It was an observation, not an answer.

Comment: There are two sources of computation error when working with floating point numbers.  One is the base conversion, values in decimal with an exact representation in base 10 (like 0.1) don't have one in base 2.  Decimal solves that one.  The other is a calculation requiring an infinite number of digits to represent the exact result.  a / b  here.  Decimal does not solve that one.  The Windows calculator program uses a lot of tricks to avoid disappointing non-programmers, a job that [is never done](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180704-00/?p=99165).  Use BigRational.

Comment: 28 decimal places should be enough for anyone :-)

Answer (score 3):

`BigRational` seems to be a good way to go:

```
decimal a = 32;
decimal b = 65;
decimal c = 130;

Numerics.BigRational d = (Numerics.BigRational)a / b * c;

decimal e = (decimal)d;
```

`e` has the value `64`.